# Visual studio live unit testing not work properly

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

When I start live unit testing in Visual Studio 2015 (15.4.2) I have a message in the output window saying

> Build completed(failed)

But if I try to build the the unit test project separately it will build without any warnings and errors.

All in all it says "Live unit tests started". But i don't get "blue" lines which indicate missing unit testing.

Comment: Looks like there is code (projects) not included in your unit tests that fail to compile, have your checked the 'Results' and 'Errors' tabs?

Comment: Logically, if the unit test builds but the whole solution does not, then some other project in the solution is failing to build. The Errors window will show you what's wrong.

Comment: I have '0 'errors/warning in that window

Comment: Further does VS live unit testing supports Rhino Mocks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues was with post build actions. I have removed them and it working fine.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a very similar issue myself in Visual Studio 2019, wanted to leave down my solution for those who may be searching for it later down the road.

To get to the actual issue, navigate to the following

> Test -> Live Unit Testing -> Options...

Then change the `Logging level` to `Verbose`. The next time you build, open the output window (`View -> Output` or `Ctrl + Alt + O`), and use the dropdown at the top of the window to select "Live Unit Testing" (Note: you may want to clear this log and run it again to in order to make it easier to interpret). Near the start of the log will be your build events, hopefully including the error you've received.

---

In my particular case, my error was due to the length of my .csproj path exceeding the 260 character limit. In order to fix this with TFVC, I had to re-map my workspace to a shorter name then build again and my tests appeared and worked fine.

Hopefully this can help save someone else a bit of searching in the future

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue and indeed the problem seems to be long path limitations.
See @MichaelM's answer, and turn on verbose logging -> this should point you to the project failing to build/ reference.

Suggestions:

- try to reduce your path by remapping your project to a shorter path (e.g. D:\x)
- try to rename your project name to a shorter version (e.g. CompanyX.FeatureY.ComponentZ.csproj -> Y.CompZ.csproj)